# CCNet Trigger different Tasks

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I would like to have two (or more) different triggers for different tasks in one project. Is this possible?
For example:
A interval Trigger to build my project ones an hour and a scheduled trigger to perform my unit test once every day.
I'm using the latest version of CCNet with MSBuild and MSTest.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it by myself and did it in two projects in the ccnet.config.
Each project has its own trigger and performs one task (build or unit test).